# Changing the iOS Password Autofill textfield order

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

So we have two `UIView`s next to eachother - think of them as cards. One contains the fields for a normal login (email, password) and the other contains fields for a registration (name, email, password, confirm password etc).

We're trying to implement the password autofill feature and it works, except the wrong fields are being populated. I'll tap on the password field of the login screen, do the biometrics, select the account I want to use the details of and that password field get populated correctly. However, a random field from the registration screen gets the email address... I've managed to work out that it's got something to do with the drawing order of the controls. Whichever `UITextField` is closest to the password field, regardless of which `UIView` it's part of, gets the email address. I'll try draw it for example:

| textField1 | . | textField2 |

|  password  |

So if `textField2` is even 1px closer to the `password` (vertically speaking), it receives the email address.

What I need to do somehow is modify the responder chain / drawing order or whatever in order to force `textField1` to receive the email address.

Any hints into what I can look at would be appreciated. We've dug through all the Apple docs regarding responder chains etc and no luck.

I have tried setting the `contentType` of the textfields to no avail.

Here's a picture of the textfield layout

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to share Code with us in order to identify and help you in your problem, if not is more complex to figure out where is the issue

Comment: I'd be happy to share code if there was code :) The entire UI is built in IB so technically, there is no code related to those fields yet... I've tried a few things with hacking the delegates but that didn't work. It's reproducible by laying out some textfield in a similar fashion as I have above (in IB) and running the app. No code required.

Comment: I'm guessing you have set the UITextContentType for each textfield as described in the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view ?

Comment: @Ocunidee I've actually tried this. Setting those seems to make no difference at all. Even changing `textField2` contentType to cell number doesn't stop it from receiving the email address :(

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type on the textfield to **email**. I have memories that this was helping password and usernames to be correctly identified and populated?

Comment: Given the layout I'm seeing, I'm guessing that this could somehow be linked to how accessibility is working (I know weird, bear with me though). For voiceover, the system has to know which is the next item to read and it doesn't follow the view hierarchy by default (by that I mean that it won't read all the elements of a UIView acting as a container before going to the next container. It will read things from left to right and then vertically.) Try adding this property to the uiview containing your login textfields: containerView.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true
It's a gamble, I know

Comment: @Pancho yup I've tried that, no luck.
@Ocunidee tried that now. Also no luck. However, do you think setting that attribute in IB within `User Defined Runtime Attributes` would be sufficient?

Comment: @ByronCoetsee it should I guess

Comment: @ByronCoetsee, I never downvote without telling why

Comment: @ReinierMelian more people should be like you ;)